# javascript encodeURIComponent returning additional characters

Tags: javascript, url, uri, urlencode

For some reason, I am getting additional code in my encoded URI's with javascript encodeURIcomponent function, namely %25 character:

My function is:

```
function twit_click() {
    var u="https://www.website.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>";
    var t="sometext";
    window.open('http://www.twitter.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(t),'twitsharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;   
}
```

when I click the text and call twit_click() function, I get the following URL:

`http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=sometext&url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.website.com%252Fuserid`

as opposed to what it should be:

`http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=sometext&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fuserid`

am I missing something? It is adding in additional "25" characters which would imply I have % in my URI which I clearly do not.

Comment: It looks like your `u` is already encoded, so you probably don't have to encode again.

Comment: looks like it's getting encoded twice. The code that you have is not the code that's generating those urls (order of qs params), so I'd look at the code that's making those urls.

Comment: @anq - yes it is. Twitter's system routes from the share page to /intent/ on its own

Comment: @PaulGrime - it may be encoded or it might not be, the $_SESSION ID variable may have special characters which in that case would not be url encoded.

Comment: try not encoding it... maybe the browser is mangling your preencoded call, I'm pretty sure it will take it unencoded.

Comment: Maybe add some `console.log`s to your code to print out `u`, `encodeURIComponent(u)`, `encodeURIComponent("/")`, etc just to make sure things are happening the way you expect. `encodeURIComponent` hasn't been overridden to double-up its encoding has it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "www" from "www.twitter" and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/tzkpz/

Twitter must be re-encoding the URL when it redirects from www.twitter.com to twitter.com, hence the double encoding.